# Execute SSIS Packages with Dependency

Tags: ssis

I have 100+ child SSIS packages that have different level of dependencies. All these packages are executed from a Master package. For example:

```
Package A, Package B, Package C, Package D, Package E

Package A and Package B have no dependency
Package C is Dependent on Package A
Package D is dependent on Package B
Package E is dependent on Package C
```

Any suggestion how to run this kind scenario from master package in parallel if there is no dependency?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a PACKAGE Named Master.
2. In Master Add two 'execute Package task', For 'Package A' and
   'Package B' resp.
3. Add a third 'execute Package task' for 'Package C'. Connect it in
   serial with 'Package A'
4. Add a fourth 'execute Package task' for 'Package D'. Connect it in
   serial with 'Package B'
5. Add one more 'execute Package task' for 'Package E'. Connect it in
   serial with 'Package C'

I think this is how you should follow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not a definitive answer to your question, it depends on the requirements, in your example can package C still run even if package A fails, just that it does not pull in any new data that package A would have provided if it ran successfully. In general, looking at the example you have provided, in the master package I would have a sequence container that contains invocations to Package A and B and a successful flow connected to another sequence container that invokes package C and D and have the package E invoked on a successful invocation of package C with in the sequence container.